# How to directly save spectrogram image to specific pixel size

Tags: python, image, spectrogram

I am generating spectrograms and casting them to images for use in a CNN.  How can I directly specify the pixel size of the spectrogram.  This is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
import librosa.display


filename = (r'G:pt5GAL_TCL_mono.wav')

y, sr = librosa.load(filename)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.specgram(y, Fs=2);
fig.savefig(f'test1.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Whith this approach, I have to save the file, then recall it to save it as a 244x244 image.

```
img = Image.open(f'test1.png')
il = img.resize((224, 224))
imageio.imwrite(f'test1.png', il)
```

How can I do this directly?  That is, save the spectrogram data directly as a 244x244 image with no white border?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the proper way to do it.

```
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(self.img_width / 100, self.img_height / 100))
        ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
        librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(feature), ref=np.max), cmap='gray_r', ax=ax)
        ax.set_axis_off()
        fig.add_axes(ax)
        plt.savefig(path, dpi=100)
        plt.close()
```

img_width and img_height are the dimensions of the image saved and feature is the sampled input signal with librosa's stft function.